# Enable ASP.NET configuration for Visual Studio 2013

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'm using Visual Studio 2013. I cannot get the ASP.NET Configuration tool. I cannot seem to locate it anywhere. Is there a plugin or something I'm missing.In the last version it was in the solution explorer window. Have they moved it. I need to set some administration settings for my site. Please Help!

Comment: what config are you talking about??

Comment: @testernick79 are you talking about ASP.NET membership ?

Comment: I'm talking about the ASP. NET admin tools. One of them is called the ASP.NET configuration to setup admin pages for a website.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you mean the tool that was removed from Visual Studio 2013 in the late beta period? If so, here is the answer:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/08/19/asp-net-web-configuration-tool-missing-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx

Comment: OK cool so how do i find out what PORT my IIS is using? In the link it tells me to list the port number.

Comment: The default would be 8081.